# angular ng-repeat input validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

before saving data in localstorage I have to verify whether user fill all the inputs.everything work fine with the exeption of input validation. up to the moment i'm not good familiar with the Angularjs.
any help highly appreciated

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.d1 = [];
  $scope.d2 = [];
  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.append = function() {
    $scope.data.push([]);
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.d1.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.d1[i].length === 0) {
        alert("fill empty fields please");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('Surname', JSON.stringify($scope.d1));
      }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.d2.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.d2[j].length === 0) {
        alert("fill empty fields please");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('Name', JSON.stringify($scope.d2));
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button ng-click="append()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">append</button>
      <button ng-click="save()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td><input ng-model="d1[$index]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input ng-model="d2[$index]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are your asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add element Name in input and use 'required' to make the field mantatory

```
   <form name="myForm" novalidate>      
..........................
<td><input ng-model="d1[$index]" type="text"
     required name="text{{$index}}" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input ng-model="d2[$index]"
     type="text" required name="text{{$index}}"class="form-control"></td>

........</form>
```

Before doing save operation check weather form valid or invalid

```
$scope.save = function() {
   if($scope.myForm.$valid){
//add code
}else{
//display error message 
}
}
```

We can display field level validation also Please refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)